# firefox strange icons against characters

Tags: firefox, unicode, fonts, locale, archlinux

I have such an issue in a lot of sites.

There were no problem on my previous Arch installation, but now.[image]

```
% locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I also `allow pages to choose they own fonts`, in `firefox` advanced options, using `serif` as a default firefox font in choosing `latin`, with `fallback text encoding` to default.

Don't know what the problem is.

All advices are already applied.

Answer (score 0):

you get those boxes (which represent unknown glyphs) because the font you're using has no character/rendering for them.  it's not because your `locale` settings are broken.

Comment: pick a different font.  if the site is using multiple fonts, figure out which one it expects, and install that in your distro.  firefox/chrome have builtin inspectors so you can select the text and have it tell you which font families it's attempting to load.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Chinese, Japanese or Korean fonts installed. Install [some of these packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fonts#Chinese.2C_Japanese.2C_Korean.2C_Vietnamese).